# Factorial de un número shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Estaba yo aquí intentando resolver el factorial de un número pasado como argumento, y como soy de esas que hacen comprobación paranoica, pues había pensado que sería interesante comprobar que si el parámetro  introducido  es una letra,  dé un error porque no se puede calcular el número factorial de una letra.

Bien, estuve navengando por el foro y encontré una forma de hacerlo, el problema es que no sé qué falla en mi código, ya que con la comprobación moviéndola de líneas no me calcula ni el factorial del número, me sale el mensaje de error que debería salir en caso de que fuese una letra, y modificando los parámetros de la comprobación, me da error siempre en una de las partes.

Os dejo por aquí mi código:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Factorial de un número pasado por parámetro:
clear 

#Primero declaramos las variables inicializadas con un valor.
#Al igual que en C, en este caso inicalizamos en 1, ya que inicializarlas en 0, la multiplicación del factorial, sería siempre 0.
factorial=1
contador=1
if test "$1" = ""; then 
    echo "El script necesita de un número entero para ejecutarse. Intentelo de nuevo. "
    sleep 2
    echo "Saliendo del script... "
    sleep 2 
    exit 1 
else 
    validar_numero='^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$'
    if ! [[ "$1"=~"$validar_numero" ]]; then 
        echo "Lo que se ha introducido no es número entero positivo. "
        exit 2
    else
        while [[ $1 -ge $contador ]]; do
            factorial=`expr $factorial \* $contador`
            contador=`expr $contador + 1`
        done
    fi
    echo "El factorial de $1 es $factorial. "
fi
```

La forma en la que ejecuto mi guión es:

```
chmod 777 factorial.sh
./factorial.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente lo que hacías era comparar dos cadenas, necesitas pasar el argumento sin convertirlo a una cadena, y arreglar tu expresión.

```
# cambiar la expresión para solo numeros 
validar_numero='^[0-9]+$'
#comparar el argumento sin convertir a cadena
if ! [[ $1 =~ $validar_numero ]]; then
```

Aquí el script completo:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Factorial de un número pasado por parámetro:
clear 

#Primero declaramos las variables inicializadas con un valor.
#Al igual que en C, en este caso inicalizamos en 1, ya que inicializarlas en 0, la multiplicación del factorial, sería siempre 0.
factorial=1
contador=1
if test "$1" = ""; then 
    echo "El script necesita de un número entero para ejecutarse. Intentelo de nuevo. "
    sleep 2
    echo "Saliendo del script... "
    sleep 2 
    exit 1 
else 
    # cambiar la expresión para solo numeros 
    validar_numero='^[0-9]+$'
    #comparar el argumento sin convertir a cadena
    if ! [[ $1 =~ $validar_numero ]]; then 
        echo "Lo que se ha introducido no es número entero positivo. "
        exit 2
    else
        while [[ $1 -ge $contador ]]; do
            factorial=`expr $factorial \* $contador`
            contador=`expr $contador + 1`
        done
    fi
    echo "El factorial de $1 es $factorial. "
fi
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Todo perfecto

Answer (score 2):

Tomando ventaja de la calculadora `bc` podemos crear un script para calcular factorial con una gran capacidad:

```
#!/bin/bash

# definir formula de factorial
fact(){ local a=$1;((a<2)) && echo "1" && return
    b='define f(n) { if (n < 2) return 1;  return n*f(n-1); };f('
        bc<<<"$b$a)"
      }

# cambiar la expresión para solo numeros 
validar_numero='^[1-9][0-9]*$'

#comparar el argumento sin convertir a cadena
if [[ $1 =~ $validar_numero ]]; then
    fact "$1"
else
    echo "El parametro no es un numero entero positivo"
fi
```

Que puede calcular pequeños y grandes factoriales:

```
$ ./fact 6
720

$ ./fact 20
2432902008176640000

$ ./fact 100
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217\
59999322991560894146397615651828625369792082722375825118521091686400\
0000000000000000000000
```

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta! ¿Podrías explicarla un poco?